# Different result in simple_query_string and match phrase

Tags: python, elasticsearch, search, nosql, full-text-search

I am getting a different result for simple_query_string and multi-match for same search keyword

elasticsearch  isversion 6.2.3

Mapping

```
{
   "test_field": {                                   
   "type": "text"
  }
}
```

Search Keyword: `java sql $`

multi_match Query

```
{
   "multi_match": {
      "query": "java sql $",
       "type": "phrase",
        "boost": 1,
         "fields": ["test_field"]
   }
}
```

record count: 2

simple_query_string Query

```
{
   "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "java sql $",
       "default_operator": "and",
        "fields": ["test_field"]
   }
}
```

record count: 0

What is the reason the multi_match and simple_query_string returning the different result for the same search keyword?

Thank you.